How can I run Tests in Compose Multiplatform from Android Studio? (command line works)
I'm currently trying to get testing setup in my first Compose Multiplatform project.
I've followed the instructions here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/compose-test.html#writing-and-running-tests-with-compose-multiplatform
So far I can run tests successfuly from the command line using:
./gradlew :composeApp:connectedAndroidTest

When I try to run them from Android Studio (GUI) I get the following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)" because "android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT" is null
at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.runTest(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:314)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.ComposeUiTest_androidKt.runAndroidComposeUiTest(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:114)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.ComposeUiTest_androidKt.runComposeUiTest(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:61)
at androidx.compose.ui.test.ComposeUiTest_androidKt.runComposeUiTest$default(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:60)
at cm.feature.game.play.TwisterViewModelTest.helloTestingCM(GameViewModelTest.kt:21)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:112)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)

Here is my test:
class GameViewModelTest {
@OptIn(ExperimentalTestApi::class)
@Test
fun helloTestingCM() = runComposeUiTest {
    setContent {
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello") }
        Text(
            text = text,
            modifier = Modifier.testTag("text")
        )
        Button(
            onClick = { text = "Compose" },
            modifier = Modifier.testTag("button")
        ) {
            Text("Click ma")
        }
    }

    // Tests the declared UI with assertions and actions of the Compose Multiplatform testing API
    onNodeWithTag("text").assertTextEquals("Hello")
    onNodeWithTag("button").performClick()
    onNodeWithTag("text").assertTextEquals("Chompose")
}

}
Is there something else I'm missing or has anyone else run into this error? I assume it's because when I run via command line it's running on real device and has the missing dependencies.

I was referring to the same test example at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/compose-test.html#62f6e1cb facing the same error.
As far as I understand you can run tests for android only from terminal:
"Currently, you cannot run common Compose Multiplatform tests using android (local) test configurations, so gutter icons in Android Studio, for example, won't be helpful."

I was able to make the Android (local) test configurations be runnable from Android Studio using Robolectric.
Add these dependencies to your source set:
val androidUnitTest by getting {
    dependencies {
        implementation(androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4)
        implementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
        implementation(libs.robolectric)
    }
}

this is my libs.versions.toml:
[versions]
compose = "1.6.7"
robolectric = "4.12"

[libraries]
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4", version.ref = "compose" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest", version.ref = "compose" }
robolectric = { module = "org.robolectric:robolectric", version.ref = "robolectric" }

I also needed to add this to my composeApp's build.gradle.kts to make resources work:
android {
    // ...
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
    }

    // add this, NOTE: it's "isIncludeAndroidResources" not "includeAndroidResources"
    testOptions.unitTests.isIncludeAndroidResources = true
}

You then just need to annotate your test:
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MyTest {
    // ...
}

That's it, it will be runnable with "Android (local)" configuration from Android Studio, and it won't give errors about "android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT" is null.
PS: I figured out this solution a long time ago, but I'm posting this answer only now. It could be I missed some important points because it's not fresh in my head what I did a long time ago to make it work. In case you have questions, ask them in the comments, I'll try to help!

This seems to be working for me, at least on a first try.
But I'm unsure of the implications of running common ui code on robolectric since robolectric is an android test library.
If someone knows more about this please let me know, I will be working writing tests for kmp-compose for an educational platform. I need to make reliable tests, that do not need real devices and that does not know implementation details other than required widgets and behaviours.
I'm used to make robolectric tests for android with xml, but I don't know what to expect using it for testing common ui code for kmp

@MauricioRodriguez The way I have it in my code is: I have an abstract class in common source set, called let's say MyCommonTest. This class contains the common tests for all platforms. Then, in my Android source set I have a class MyTest that inherits from MyCommonTest, and adds some more tests specific to Android. I then annotate the MyTest class with @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class), and not the MyCommonTest. This way I run MyTest with Robolectric, which makes sense since it's from the Android source set. And MyCommonTest doesn't use Robolectric at all.
